# Is there a reduced form of the dot product in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I am trying to find a numpy operation that gives me the scalar products between all vectors of a 2d array at index i of a 3d array and the vector at index i of a 2d array. Let me give you an example to explain what I am thinking of:

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3],
              [2,3,4]],
             
             [[11,12,13],
              [12,13,14]]])

y = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [2,2,2]])



np.?operation?(x,y.T)

output:
[[[1 *1 + 1 *2 + 1 *3], 
  [1 *2 + 1 *3 + 1 *4]],

 [[2 *11 + 2 *12 + 2 *13], 
  [2 *12 + 2* 13 + 2 *14]]]

= [[[6], 
    [9]],

   [[72], 
    [78]]]
```

As you can see, I am basically looking for a reduced dot product operation. The dot product of x and y would yield the following:

```
np.dot(x, y.T)

output:
[[[ 6 12]
  [ 9 18]]

 [[36 72]
  [39 78]]]
```

Or is there a way to extract the results I need from the dot product result?

I have also tried np.tensordot(x,y,axis) but I were not able to figure which tuples I should put for -axis-.
I have also come across the np.einsum() operation but couldn't work my head around how this could help me with my problem.

Comment: Add an extra dimension in `y` so they can broadcast and then multiply and sum: [`(x * y[:, None]).sum(axis=-1)`](https://akuiper.com/console/A712HMuLo8RT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be doable with `np.einsum` or `np.matmul/@` which has a "batch" operation on the leading dimension.  But sorting out your dimensions, and getting the (2,2,1) shape is a bit tricky.

Your `np.dot(x, y.T)` gives the numbers you want, but you have to extract a kind of diagonal on 2, while retaining a dimension.

Here's one way of doing this - it isn't the fastest or succinct, but should help me wrap my mind around the dimensions.

```
In [432]: y[:,None,:]
Out[432]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2]]])
In [433]: y[:,None,:].repeat(2,1)
Out[433]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
In [435]: x*y[:,None,:].repeat(2,1)
Out[435]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  3,  4]],

       [[22, 24, 26],
        [24, 26, 28]]])
In [436]: (x*y[:,None,:].repeat(2,1)).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
Out[436]: 
array([[[ 6],
        [ 9]],

       [[72],
        [78]]])
```

We don't need the repeat, `broadcasting` will take its place:

```
(x*y[:,None,:]).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

This `einsum` does the same as the `dot/@`:

```
In [441]: np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl',x,y)
Out[441]: 
array([[[ 6, 12],
        [ 9, 18]],

       [[36, 72],
        [39, 78]]])
```

Change the indices a bit to get the "diagonal" (`i` in all terms)

```
In [442]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',x,y)
Out[442]: 
array([[ 6,  9],
       [72, 78]])
```

and add a trailing dimension:

```
In [443]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',x,y)[:,:,None]
Out[443]: 
array([[[ 6],
        [ 9]],

       [[72],
        [78]]])
```

Now that I have the `einsum` I can visualize the `matmul/@` dimensions.  I need to the treat the first dimension of both as the 'batch', and add a new trailing dimension to `y`, making it (2,3,1).   (2,2,3) with (2,3,1) => (2,2,1) with sum-of-products on the 3.

```
In [445]: x@y[:,:,None]
Out[445]: 
array([[[ 6],
        [ 9]],

       [[72],
        [78]]])
```

If `x` and `y` were (4,2,3) and (4,3) shaped, this dimension matching would have been more obvious.

```
In [446]: X=x.repeat(2,0)
In [447]: Y=y.repeat(2,0)
In [448]: X.shape
Out[448]: (4, 2, 3)
In [449]: Y.shape
Out[449]: (4, 3)
In [450]: X@Y[:,:,None]    # (4,2,1)
Out[450]: 
array([[[ 6],
        [ 9]],

       [[ 6],
        [ 9]],

       [[72],
        [78]],

       [[72],
        [78]]])
```

With these shapes it's more obvious that `4` is the batch, and `3` is the sum-of-products.